# Absolute value inequality in sequence proof

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, inequality

How do we get the inequality below?

---

Ross - Elementary Analysis

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

If $s > 0$, then we have

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{s_n}} \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{s}}$$

For the $n$'s s.t. $s_n - s \ge 0$, we have

$$\frac{s_n - s}{\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{s_n}} \le \frac{s_n - s}{\sqrt{s}}$$

$$\to \sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s} \le \frac{s_n - s}{\sqrt{s}}$$

$$\to \sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s} \le \frac{|s_n - s|}{\sqrt{s}}\tag{1}$$

Otherwise, we have

$$\frac{s_n - s}{\sqrt{s} + \sqrt{s_n}} \ge \frac{s_n - s}{\sqrt{s}}$$

$$\to \sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s} \ge \frac{s_n - s}{\sqrt{s}}$$

$$\to \sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s} \ge \frac{-|s_n - s|}{\sqrt{s}}\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we have

$$\frac{-|s_n - s|}{\sqrt{s}} \le \sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s} \le \frac{|s_n - s|}{\sqrt{s}}$$

Thus

$$|\sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s}| \le \frac{|s_n - s|}{\sqrt{s}}$$

Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good to me. Alternatively,
$$
\sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s} = \frac{s_n - s}{\sqrt{s_n} + \sqrt{s}} \Rightarrow
|\sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s}| = \frac{|s_n - s|}{\sqrt{s_n} + \sqrt{s}} \Rightarrow
|\sqrt{s_n} - \sqrt{s}| \leq \frac{|s_n - s|}{\sqrt{s}}$$

Comment: LOL thanks NP-hard ^-^